# WinSCP authentication with an OpenSSH-created Ed25519 (non ppk) private key - possible?

Tags: ssh, putty, sftp, openssh, winscp

I created an Ed25519 SSH key pair with OpenSSH on Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL) and I would like to use it to SFTP into my Ubuntu16 VPS; I have now noticed that as of */12/2016, WinSCP (latest version: 5.9.3) doesn't process these keys naturally.

I could hope to export it to `.ppk` with Putty but as of today, Putty does not support working with Ed25519.

Is there any setting or plugin for WinSCP to support this authentication method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP supports the .ppk private keys only.

But it can convert private keys from OpenSSH format to the .ppk format, including the ed25519 keys.

Just select the private key file on the [*Authentication* page of Advanced Site Settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication). WinSCP will ask you, if you want to convert the key:

[image]

---

Version 0.68 and newer of PuTTY/PuTTYgen [supports the ed25519 keys](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ed25519.html) too.

Comment: Hi. Even after conversion I can't use the key (authentication failure). I also can't create Ed25519 keys with Puttygen, so it seem not to. It's the most latest version (0.67).

Comment: Are you sure it is in the latest version?  The [commit that](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=commit;h=541abf92583cd93f3952aa0e3b8f61ba9251f3fa) supposedly added the ed25519 support modifies the sshecc.c file, but that doesn't seem to exist in [the 0.67 tag](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=tree;h=58dea93898e2333197cfce3cae17246a31ab1a07;hb=830b7f8898bf05c95e97ba6cc88692637cc8f60a).  I am guessing this is a dev branch only feature?

Comment: Maybe... I think I'll just use rsa-4096 for now, it seems to be experimental in these aforementioned software and I really want to keep using WinSCP so RSA 4096 seems as my best option.

Comment: @Zoredache You are right. I've fixed my answer.